# CSS working in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress, cross-browser

I have added a search menu to header.php in WordPress HTML:

```
 <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                  <?php
                  // Main menu
                  echo $primary_menu;
                  ?>
                  <div id="search"><?php get_search_form();?></div>
                            </div><!--end container-->
```

I added `<div id="search"><?php get_search_form();?></div>` to the existing template.

I have made some style changes to the search menu: `.input-group .form-control {height:36px !important;}`

These changes are implemented in Firefox but are not visible in Chrome. When I inspect the element with Firebug you can see the code is visible. When I inspect the element in Chrome it doesn't (as far as I can see) appear at all.

I have not applied any cross browser CSS should I? What cardinal sin have I commited?

The website URL is: [Homepage](http://genup.co.uk)

Thanks.

Comment: *"What cardinal sin have I commited?"* You need to include just the minimal amount of code needed to replicate the issue in the post itself to give us a [mcve].

Comment: Looks like it's there to me http://i.imgur.com/uNfNnb0.png

Comment: I suppose you flushed your browser cache? If not try ctrl-f5 for hard refresh, dev tools setting disable cache, privacy mode ctrl+shift+n.

Comment: Dammit! Sorry. I thought I had flushed my Cache by I hadnt on Chrome. Thanks for your help. Sometimes it is the looking you right in the eyes!

Answer (score 0):

You are using too many "!important" statements. Your CSS shows:

```
.input-group {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    width: 380px !important;
    background-color: #f4f4f4 !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    margin-left: 450px !important;
}
```

and then:

```
.input-group .form-control {
    height:36px !important;
}
```

So you are applying !important twice and it is causing the problem. Please remove the statements and it should work:

```
.input-group {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    width: 380px !important;
    background-color: #f4f4f4 !important;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 450px !important;
}

.input-group .form-control {
    height:36px;
}
```