# Why loading images is not working in chrome whereas in mozilla is being loaded, in CSS3?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, chromium

Last week I started working on my project using react with webpack, but CSS is making my life difficult, I set the webpack and it was working well. When I came to style, I set the background image of a div but it refused to get loaded in chromium browser and chrome but in mozilla firefox it is being loaded. I even uninstalled chromium and reinstalled it again but still the problem is there. I cleared the browsing data from the chromium but still the problem exists.

My codes:

Here is my CSS:

```
    .full-div {
      background: url("../img/slides/slide-1.jpg") center center fixed no-repeat;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
```

And my react codes:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import customMsg from '../utils/customMessages';

    class HomePage extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {};
      }

      render() {
        const { welcomeMessage } = customMsg;
        return (
          <div className="full-div">
            <h1>{welcomeMessage}</h1>
            <img alt="foto1" src="../assets/img/slides/slide-2.jpeg" />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default HomePage;
```

Setting Background image in CSS3 is not working in chrome and loading img with `<img alt="foto1" src="../assets/img/slides/slide-2.jpeg" />` is not working as well.

Here is my webpack config:

```
    const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
    const path = require('path');
    require('dotenv').config();

    module.exports = (env) => ({
      context: __dirname,
      entry: './src/entry/index.js',
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'descholar.js',
        publicPath: '/',
      },
      mode: env ? 'production' : 'development',
      devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: process.env.PORT,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
      },

      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['babel-loader'],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(css)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
          },
          {
            test: /.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$/,
            use: ['file-loader',
              {
                loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                options: {
                  mozjpeg: {
                    progressive: true,
                    quality: 65,
                  },
                  // optipng.enabled: false will disable optipng
                  optipng: { enabled: false },
                  pngquant: {
                    quality: '65-90',
                    speed: 4,
                  },
                  gifsicle: { interlaced: false },
                  // the webp option will enable WEBP
                  webp: { quality: 75 },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
          template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'),
          filename: 'index.html',
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: '[name].css',
          chunkFilename: '[id].css',
        }),
      ],
      performance: {
        hints: false,
      },
    });
```

I even re-set my project with `create-react-app` but still the problem is there, that means probably my setup doesn't have any issue, maybe the issue is the browser, does anyone knows anything about that issue? Or should I open an issue on react official repo!

I read this question [CSS working in Firefox but not Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655300/css-working-in-firefox-but-not-chrome) but it is not my case

Answer (score 0):

You should try importing the images like:

`import slide-1 from '../img/slides/slide-1.jpg'`

After you import, you can use it in the JS file by going:

`<img src={slide-1} alt="Slide1" />`

According to the `create-react-app` docs

```
You can import a file right in a JavaScript module. This tells webpack 
to include that file in the bundle. Unlike CSS imports, importing a file 
gives you a string value. This value is the final path you can reference 
in your code, e.g. as the src attribute of an image or the href of a link 
to a PDF.
```

Comment: I understand that is okay but wait, what about the background in CSS?

Comment: You could in that instance create a style object in the component with the backgrounImage and set it in the component html